# Getting a random answer at end of list that shouldn't be there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have answers associated with a question. Each time I create a question, there should be no answers associated with it because none have been created. However, I seem to get a blank answer where no text or anything exists, and the like/dislike links for that answer are entirely invalid. I have content verification in the answer model, so I'm not sure why this extra answer is being created.

This is where I have my question with answers under it

```
<% @question.answers.each do |ans| %>
        <div class="container">
            <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #888888; box-shadow: 5px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)">
            </p>

            <h5><%= ans.answer %></h5>
            <p><em><%= ans.commenter %></em> posted</p>
            <p>
                <%= ans.likes.size %> | <%= link_to "vote up", like_question_answer_path([@question],[ans]), method: :put%> | <%= link_to "vote down", dislike_question_answer_path([@question],[ans]), method: :put%> | <%= link_to "Comments", [@question, ans] %>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my answer model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :question
    attr_accessible :anonymous, :answer, :commenter, :votes, :comments_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
    validates :answer, presence: true, length: {minimum: 10}
    acts_as_votable
end
```

And this is the controller for that particular view

```
def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answer = @question.answers.new(params[:answer])
end
```

I thought the validation for validating answer presence and length would get rid of the extra post, since this extra post has NOTHING in the answer text box. 
So I have an extra, blank answer whose commenter is also blank. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The `@answer = @question.answers.new(params[:answer])` line will always initialize a new `Answer` and add it to the `@question`'s `answers` collection. When you iterate through the answers in your view, that collection will include the `@answer` record you initialized in the controller.

Comment: Also, you seem to be closing a `<div>` tag with a `</p>` at the top of your question loop, so you might want to fix that...

Comment: But why is it initializing a new answer even though it's an invalid answer? It has 0 length for the answer, which is less than 10. How would I be able to avoid it being added?

Comment: An invalid record will still be initialized, it just won't be *persisted*. See my answer below to avoid having it be initialized into the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid initializing the extra `Answer` record into the collection, use the following in the controller

```
def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answer = Answer.new(params[:answer]).tap { |a| a.question = @question }
end
```

Using the `new` method off of the `@question.answers` collection will initialize the new record and add it into the collection (which you don't want in this case).

Comment: Not sure if Rails 3.2 doesn't work but I get undefined method merge-

Comment: Not sure the context that you are using `@answer`, but if you definitely need to set the `question_id`, then try the updated method above.

Comment: When you call `@question.answers.new(...)`, it will do the following: (1) create a new `Answer` instance (2) set the `question_id` attribute of the `Answer` equal to the id of `@question` and (3) add the new record into the `@question.answers` collection. Since #3 was what was causing you trouble, we had to create the instance manually ourselves (i.e. #1) via `Answer.new` and the `tap` part sets the `question_id` (i.e. #2).